# Appending to existing file from resource file in Linux C Program

Tags: c, linux, append, mode

i've trying to perform appending to an existing file from resource file using the C programming in Linux. However, my code doesn't work for that, can any1 do tell me what's wrong with the code and also how O_APPEND is working? thanks :)

```
char ifile[150];
char tfile[150];
char cc;

system("clear");
printf("Please enter your resource file name : ");
gets(ifile);
printf("Please enter your destination file name : ");
gets(tfile);

int in, out;

in = open(ifile, O_RDONLY);
int size = lseek(in,0L,SEEK_END);
out = open(tfile, O_WRONLY |O_APPEND);
char block[size];
int pdf;
while(read(in,&block,size) == size)
    pdf = write(out,&block,size);
close(in);close(out);
if(pdf != -1)
    printf("Successfully copy!");
else
    perror("Failed to append! Error : ");
printf("Press enter to exit...");
do
{
    cc = getchar();
} while(cc != '\n');
```

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: `while(read(in,&block,size) == size)` will fail if the last block of the file has a size unequal to size (oops, I had not seen the lseek() ...) . (which is probable, unless size==1.). Also: don't use gets(). It is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: well, after operation the target file still remain the same... the append not working

Comment: Did you check the results of the open to make sure the files opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you deplace the reading cursor at the end of the file in order to know its size, but you don't rewind to the start of the file to be able to read. So `read()` reads `EOF`, and returns `0`.

```
int size = lseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
out = open(tfile, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
```

should be

```
int size = lseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
lseek(in, 0L, SEEK_SET);
out = open(tfile, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
```

In addition, when you read and write, you should use `block` and not `&block`, since `block` is already a pointer (or an address).

Oh, and also... When you open the file `out` for writing... It will fail if the file does not exist already.

Here how to create it with rights set to 644:

```
out = open(tfile, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

(This won't have any effect if the file already exists)